# OpenGL - gluOrtho2d and glLoadIdentity?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm starting out on OpenGL. I'm not sure how `gluOrtho2d` and `glLoadIdentity` play out together. In particular, I have the following code, which is supposed to draw a 2x2 square in the center of a 10x10 display.

```
int main() {
    glutCreateWindow("Draw A Square");
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void mydisplay() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawAUnitSquare();

    glFlush();
}

void drawAUnitSquare() {
    // glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(-1, -1);
        glVertex2f(1, -1);
        glVertex2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    glEnd();
}
```

The above code works. However, if I uncomment the `glLoadIdentity();` in `drawAUnitSquare()`, the square then fills the entire viewport. What is happening here?

Comment: Obligatory comment - you are using immediate mode, which has been deprecated for a long time. It might be a little easier to start with, but eventually you'll have to throw it away and start learning modern OpenGL, so you might as well start learning that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to switch the matrix mode back to `GL_MODELVIEW`.

Just add `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` after `gluOrtho2D(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);`.